# Override an existing folder with cp

Tags: command-line, cp

Is it possible to override an existing folder with cp? Example:

```
tux@linux:~ $ cd /tmp/test/
tux@linux:/tmp/test $ mkdir A
tux@linux:/tmp/test $ cd A
tux@linux:/tmp/test/A $ touch 1 2 3 4
tux@linux:/tmp/test/A $ cd ..
tux@linux:/tmp/test $ cp -R A A.bak
tux@linux:/tmp/test $ tree
.
├── A
│   ├── 1
│   ├── 2
│   ├── 3
│   └── 4
└── A.bak
    ├── 1
    ├── 2
    ├── 3
    └── 4

2 directories, 8 files
tux@linux:/tmp/test $ touch A/5
tux@linux:/tmp/test $ tree
.
├── A
│   ├── 1
│   ├── 2
│   ├── 3
│   ├── 4
│   └── 5
└── A.bak
    ├── 1
    ├── 2
    ├── 3
    └── 4

2 directories, 9 files
tux@linux:/tmp/test $ cp -R A A.bak
tux@linux:/tmp/test $ tree
.
├── A
│   ├── 1
│   ├── 2
│   ├── 3
│   ├── 4
│   └── 5
└── A.bak
    ├── 1
    ├── 2
    ├── 3
    ├── 4
    └── A
        ├── 1
        ├── 2
        ├── 3
        ├── 4
        └── 5

3 directories, 14 files
```

But it should be:

```
.
├── A
│   ├── 1
│   ├── 2
│   ├── 3
│   ├── 4
│   └── 5
└── A.bak
    ├── 1
    ├── 2
    ├── 3
    ├── 4
    └── 5

2 directories, 10 files
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what you are looking for

```
cp -TRv A A.bak
```

When you use the option `-T` it overwrites the contents, treating the destination like a normal file and not directory.

from `man cp` :

```
-T, --no-target-directory
    treat DEST as a normal file

-v, --verbose
          explain what is being done
```

Alternatively, you copy the directory's contents and not the directory, like so:

```
cp -TR A/* A.bak
```

Comment: I have tried `cp -R A -t A.bak`, but it didn't work. What does `-t` mean?

Comment: what do you mean by *didn't work* ? I tried same setup on machine, it worked as you were expecting.

Comment: @user179723 `t` is not the same as `T`.

Comment: @user179723 do `man cp`. you will come to know the difference between `-t` and `-T`.